# Svelte app returning "unexpected character @ " error when running project

Tags: semantic-ui, svelte

I added a `semantic-ui-css-only` npm module in a svelte app project. Imported the module `import "../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.css";` in  `main.js` file. When I run `npm run dev` I get this error `Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)` Not sure what the solution is. My hypothesis is the @ characters in the CSS causing issues no.

Comment: Yes, you can't import CSS in JS fille without a specific plugin to transform it. What's your bundler, Rollup? Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Semantic development is dead but you can replace it with [Fomantic](https://fomantic-ui.com/)

read this issue [Is Semantic UI development dead ?](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6109)
and this [The future of Fomantic as v3.0](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI/issues/319)

After talking about this, how about this rollup plugin ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-css-only

#### main.js

```js
import App from './App.svelte';
import 'fomantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'world'
    }
});

export default app;
```

#### rollup.config.js

```js
...
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
...

plugins: [
    svelte({
        dev: !production,
        css: css => {
            css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
        }
    }),
    css({ output: './public/build/base.css' }),
    ...
    ...
]
```

#### index.html

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/base.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>
```